# Time lag unity and photon

Tags: unity-game-engine, networking, synchronization, photon

If I start the game on one instance of the game it can take even 5 minutes to sync on the other instances that the game has started

```
   [PunRPC]
    void StartGame()
    {
        StartCoroutine(Delay());
        //StartButton.SetActive(false);
    }
```

thats the function im using the regural PunRpc but that doesnt happen only with the start of the game it can happen with the transform of the players which im using the normal photon transform view. I wonder is thats my fault of doing something or i dont have the right settings or Its that im just using the free version of the services that photon provides. If you can help please do. Thanks for reading if you have any questions let me know

Comment: This is a bit hard to reproduce .. especially without the rest of your code/project ... In general if you want it guaranteed to be sync try to use the options `RpcTarget.AllViaServer` -> `Usually, when the sending client has to execute an RPC, it does so immediately - without sending the RPC through the server. This, however, affects the order of events, because there is no lag when you call a method locally. RPCs sent through the server are executed in the same order by all receiving clients.`

Comment: hello thanks for responding. I will try that but do you have any ideas of how can i fix the movement because i think that the most important is movement. And will the RpcTarget.AllViaServer fix the time lag because thats the problem im having not that it doesnt appear to all the clients

Comment: And I can give whatever you need you can just tell me what part of the code you need and ill send it to you